# AngularJS select creates option with value "? object:null ?" and doesn't use empty default option when bound to null

Tags: angularjs

Here's what the code looks like

```
<select ng-model="nullableInt">
  <option></option>
  <option value="0">First option</option>
  <option value="1">First option</option>
  <option value="2">First option</option>
</select>
```

When nullableInt is null the generated html is

```
<select ng-model="nullableInt">
  <option></option>
  <option value="? object:null ?"></option>
  <option value="0">First option</option>
  <option value="1">First option</option>
  <option value="2">First option</option>
</select>
```

Reproduced in the plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/05pBEMJppmkrn3nFgYdk?p=info

It's worth mentioning that I'm trying to avoid using `ng-options`, it seems like a bit of overkill to create an endpoint for AngularJS to consume some data that really will not change very often, if ever.

Comment: angularjs is inconsistent when it comes to the default select option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686118/angularjs-null-value-for-select

Comment: had a similar problem ? number:0 ? fixed by making the default value of model a string instead of int e.g mymodel = "0" instead of mymodel = 0;

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Update 3/29/2017:

As Jorge Rodrigues dos Santos stated, this should be handled in a different way for newer versions of angular. Below is taken from the current documentation for angular 1.6.3

> Optionally, a single hard-coded  element, with the value set
>   to an empty string, can be nested into the  element. This
>   element will then represent the null or "not selected" option. See
>   example below for demonstration.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

---

Angular is creating a new option to represent the null value. It didn't find one of the options you provided in the HTML.

To bind to null, set the value="null" on the first option

```
<option value="null"></option>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kzPVu4hiMcP6wA6crGYt?p=preview

Comment: lol.  wow.  Seriously, I read the docs and could have sworn they said to use `<option></option>`.  Good call, solved it just fine.  Will mark as answer soon.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with more recent angular versions

Comment: I dont think this is the answer. The actual value is `"null"` instead of `null`

Comment: @kazupooot this post over 3 years old...but I believe for the angular version at the time (1.2.16) a null model value would result in the select element initially having option with the value set to `"null"` being selected. At that point I think the model's value was still `null`. This is what the op was asking for. If the user selected another option and then re-selected first option, the value would then be set to `"null"` as you noted.

Comment: always be carefull with select and value vs ng-value: String representation (or identifier) vs real object

Comment: Tested this with the select options using ng-repeat and it works just fine!! Maps out the null option correctly to model. Angular version 1.6.6

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me because my property could be blank, null, or undefined. If you are using version 1.3+ then you can use a getterSetter to coerce the value to blank.

I was dealing with string values. You'll have to handle 0 or other valid falsy values in the function as well.

```
$scope.nullableIntCoerced = function(n) {
    return arguments.length ? ($scope.nullableInt = n) : ($scope.nullableInt || "");
}

<select ng-model="nullableIntCoerced" ng-model-options="{getterSetter:true}">
    <option value=""></option>
    ...
```

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Answer (score 1):

For more recent versions of Angularjs use `<option value=""> - </option>` for the null value

Answer (score 0):

Below solution solved the problem for me.

The problem here is when ng-model is used, it adds a default option with value "?" and without using ng-model, one can not use ng-change to get the current selection. I have actually created an onChangeSelection() within which we can set the defaultSelected property of the  like below

```
$scope.onChangeSelection = function(id) {

    document.getElementById(id)[0].defaultSelected = true;
    $scope.selected = $('#'+id).val();
}

<select id="mySelect" ng-model="nullableInt" ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in arrayContents track by option.value"                    ng-change="{{onChangeSelection(id)}}" required>
    <option value="" ng-if="false"></option>
</select>
```

This would exclude the default option from the options list and also make the first value as defaultSelected.

Comment: Sorry but if this would be the only solution, i would never ever use the component select. Way too complex for a single selection component.