# AngularJS null value for select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I couldn't find an elegant way for setting `null` values with a `<select>` using AngularJS.

HTML :

```
<select ng-model="obj.selected">
  <option value=null>Unknown</option>
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="0">No</option>
</select>

{{obj}}
```

JS :

```
$scope.obj ={"selected":null};
```

When the page is loaded, the first option is selected, which is good, and the output is `{"selected":null}`. When that first option is reselected after having switch to another one, the output becomes `{"selected":"null"}` (with the quotes), which is not what I would expect.

Running example : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/WuJrBBGuHGqbKq6yL4La

I know that the markup `<option value=null>` is not correct. I also tried with `<option value="">` but it corresponds to an empty String and not to null : the first option is therefore not selected and another option which disappears after the first selection is selected by default.

Any idea ?

Comment: What do you need this plain `null` for?

Comment: You can't use null. It ISNT a value, and angular needs a value to track.

Comment: @creimers `null` is permitted by the [JSON specifications](http://www.json.org/). I do not want to have some code which converts empty string to null (empty string may have another semantics)

Comment: angularjs is inconsistent when it comes to the default select option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643712/angularjs-select-creates-option-with-value-objectnull-and-doesnt-use-emp

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This should work for you:

Controller:

```
  function MyCntrl($scope) {
    $scope.obj ={"selected":null};
    $scope.objects = [{id: 1, value: "Yes"}, {id: 0, value: "No"}]
  }
```

Template:

```
  <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">

    <select ng-model="obj.selected"
            ng-options="value.id as value.value for value in objects">
            <option value="">Unknown</option>
    </select>

<br/>
     {{obj}}
  </div>
```

[Working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FrBhVlLyHQejFTumrPXT?p=preview)

You should use ng-options with select.

Comment: This solution worked. I did a small change : the objects list is defined in the `ng-options` tag in order to keep my controller clean. Thanks !

Comment: I wish this solution was explained further to understand how everything works.

Comment: Could you please update your plnkr to use newer version of Angular? For instance it does not work with version 1.4.1.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) directive on the `select`. According to the documentation:

> Optionally, a single hard-coded `<option>` element, with the value set to an empty string, can be nested into the `<select>` element. This element will then represent the `null` or "not selected" option. See example below for demonstration.

```
<select ng-model="obj.selected" ng-options="key as label for (key, label) in ['No', 'Yes']">
  <option value="">Unknown</option>
</select>
```

It's obviously a better idea to define the options list directly in the controller.

Answer (score 3):

Try using ng-options instead of manually creating  tags, as in this example, lightly-edited from the Angular docs:

http://plnkr.co/edit/DVXwlFR6MfcfYPNHScO5?p=preview

The operative parts here are lines 17, defining a 'colors' object, and the ng-options attributes iterating over those colors to create options.

Answer (score 2):

If you REALLY want to use null, see below. You need to use ng-options and let Angular handle the mapping:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Color selector</title>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.8/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="">
    <script>
  function MyCntrl($scope) {
    $scope.obj ={"selected":null};
    $scope.objStates = [{key:"Unknown", value:null}, {key:"Yes", value:1}, {key:"No", value:0}]

    $scope.$watch('obj.selected', function(newVal){
      console.log(newVal);
    })
  }
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">

    <select ng-model="obj.selected" ng-options="state.value as state.key for state in objStates">
    </select>

<br/>
     {{obj}}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks nice and that is what I'd like to do, but it doesn't work. Try this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4TuO0z4c0dBWrl14zHBw?p=preview). If you set the value to Yes and then back to Unknown, you'll notice that there is a en extra bogus option. @Wawy's solution doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same Problem but could not solve it via 'ng-options'. My solution is:

```
module.directive('modelToNull', [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            check: "&modelToNull"
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                return value == null || $scope.check({value: value}) ? null : value;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

You can use it like this:

```
<select ng-model="obj.selected" model-to-null="value == 'null'">
  <option value="null">Unknown</option>
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="0">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you can manage option values client side, it could be implemented without matcher and scope: `link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) { ngModelController.$formatters.push(function (value) { return value == null ? 'null' : value;}); ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(value) { return value === 'null' ? null : value; }); }` Plus this one will be working both directions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use `parseInt` on the value? For example, both `"1"` and `"0"` will equal their respective integer values. If you run the empty string through `parseInt` you can easily get `NaN`.

```
> parseInt("") = NaN

> parseInt("0") === 0

> parseInt("1") === 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the possibility of using ng-options I present another fix.

I've been battling this a couple of months now, using solutions presented on this question and I don't know how nobody posted this:

```
<option value="null"></option>
```

This should work on Angular 1.6 and above for sure when you are using ng-repeat for options instead of ng-options.

It's not ideal but since we are used to work on legacy code this simple fix could save your day.

Answer (score -1):

the only way you can achieve that is by using a onchange event and restoring the object as initialized any other attempt to set the selected to null will remove the property from the object.

```
$scope.setValue=function(val){
  if($scope.obj.selected=="null")
     $scope.obj ={"selected":null};
}

<select ng-change="setValue()" ng-model="obj.selected">
  <option value=null ng-click="obj.selected=null">Unknown</option>
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="0">No</option>
</select>
```

this is a bad idea, you should always have values in your model instead of playing around with null and undefined

Comment: I have to disagree ... When nothing is selected, the `null`value is more meaningful than the empty string. As shown in the selected answer, this not 'playing', the code is clearer because I do not have do some interpretation over the empty string. Null is null from the front-end to the database.

Comment: from data management point of view you are right it makes sense using null values. when talking about DOM and browser compatibility is a more  complicated issue, since having some value assigned to null could have different outcomes and unwanted results...

Comment: Im dealing with a similar issue, and <option value ></option> parses value into null, fwiw

Answer (score -2):

This is much easier on Angular2/Angular where you can just use

```
<option [value]="null">Unknown</option>
```

This value is no longer a string, but a real null value.